# My pc is under performing?

Tags: windows-7, gpu, cpu-usage, lag, fps

I recently built a gaming pc and i thought i would be able to play games on medium or high settings. 
My specs are:
i5-2400
AMD Rx 460 2gb
8gb ddr3 
Windows 7

I don't really know what the problem is? 
I have tried:
Virus Scanning
CCleaner
Different Game Settings
Defragmenting HDD
Drivers Up to Date
Not Overheating Temperatures are okay.
Capping FPS

I honestly don't know what the problem is. I just want to play some easy to run games for example Skyrim. I should be able to run skyrim yet it lags.

When I start playing my FPS fluctuates like crazy anywhere from 0-40ish FPS
I have installed MSI Afterburner and was monitoring the CPU and GPU while playing. I noticed that most of the time my GPU is at 100% while my CPU is under performing (I think) at usually 15% to 35% at the absolute peak.

So I'm literally just seeking help with this problem which I have been having for a while now. Thanks.

Comment: Did you update your drivers?

Comment: An RX 460 definitely isn't a high end card but it should manage the game okay. In the case of Skyrim I would recommend turning down the shadow quality a bit. I've had problems with shadows set at anything above medium. Shadows add some visual benefits but they can severely hamper performance. Even on a GTX 770 with Skyrim I could put most settings up to maximum, but turn up shadow quality and everything just ran horribly.

Comment: What exact settings, resolution, and mods (if any), are you running?

Comment: I'm tried running at high settings, and 1080p.I also tried 720p but it didn't seem to help.

Comment: the old i5 and the mid range GPU are not fast enough for games in high settings

Comment: The thing is that I should be able to play in medium settings at least and yet I can't do that. I even tried low settings. I get 30-40 ps but with a severe spike in fps every 2 seconds, which makes the game unplayable.

Comment: Maybe part of the problem is your disk IO - How much time does your hard drive light spend on, and, when playing at low settings do your lag spikes correspond with hard disk activity?

Answer (score 0):

From your description, the problem seems to be that your GPU is the part that is underperforming - 100% generally indicates 100% utilised, so no spare cycles to go any faster.

Also, because its a game it is likely to be graphics intensive - and the CPU is almost certainly handing off the graphics calculations to the GPU.

I'm not a gamer - but I understand the RX460 is an entry level card, and with 2 gigs of RAM on high quality it probably is unable to keep up.

Comment: I'm currently looking at the temperatures. Do you know what the temperatures should be while I'm playing games? Because I'm not sure if my temperatures are high now that I checked.

Comment: Sorry, Not really.  According to http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-3229947/gigabyte-460-gaming-temp.html less then 80c is safe, 50-70 is typical.  According to an Intel guide, the CPU temperature is not designed to go over 72.6c - note that lower temperatures indicate better cooling and are better - they do not indicate a system is not going as fast as it can.  If the temperatures are high, and the system is under performing you should check the clock speeds to ensure it is not under-clocking itself to keep within its thermal design envelope.

Comment: The temperatures seem to be fine then. I'm not sure why I'm underperforming then. I have looked at several benchmarks for my CPU and gpu and I should be able to run games at 60fps or lower st about medium quality.